# WIZnet W5500 arduino connection

Tags: arduino, pcb, ethernet

I am trying to make PCB with arduino and w5500 . I am looking example schematics. I didn't understand one thing. [image]

Normally I am connecting with 7 pin like this but when I look the example schematic [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/arduino-Ethernet-Shield2-V2-sch.pdf) they make it with 6 pins. I didn'T understand why they didn't use SCSN pin (IO10/SS)[image]

In this photo I am looking on ICSP line which is 6pins. Probably It is providing internet. If someone know, can you explain why they used 6 pins (or did they). Thank you.

Comment: which pin 6 are you asking about? ... the schematic you included has five of them

Comment: This schematic has GND, 5V,MOSI,MISO,SCK. IOSS pin is not connected . I want to know why because When o use wiznett end Arduino, I am using 7 pin

Comment: probably because the schematic diagram is not the same as your device

Comment: This schematic is w5500 chip's schematic. I am using a w5500 not chip. I am trying to make PCB that's why I am asking. I want to know why they connected like this.

Comment: Yes , I am using W5500 but [this](https://tr-m.banggood.com/Geekcreit-W5500-Ethernet-Module-TCP-or-IP-Protocol-Stack-SPI-Interface-IOT-Shield-p-1600005.html?gmcCountry=TR&currency=TRY&cur_warehouse=CN&createTmp=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 7 wires between the W5500 module and the Mega on the picture in your question.

Pins 50 MISO, 51 MOSI and 52 SCK on Mega are the same SPI pins as on the 2x3 ICSP header. Pin 53 is the SS pin of Mega so it is used as CS pin for the first slave (as usual for classic ATmega since the SS pin must be output if the ATmega is SPI master).

On the schematics in the question the ICSP header is used for SPI pins and pin 10 is used as CS as usual on Arduino shields (it is the SS pin on Uno). It is the same on the original Arduino Ethernet 2 shield with W5500.

Comment: Yes, that is my connection but look at the sparkfun's PCB design. Why re they didn't connect CS pin ?

Comment: @mrneedshelpalot they use pin 10 as it is the SS pin of Uno so a usual CS pin on Arduino shields. it is the same on the Arduino Ethernet 2 shield with W5500

Comment: Ohhh, I see. Sparkfun iş using 7 pin as well. Thank you for your explation.